# Getting rid of elevation difference between flat plane and designed DEM output

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

Does anyone know how to hide/ eliminate the height/elevation between the flat plane and the top of the DEM model (denoted with the red markup)?
I am thinking of either

1. just not showing the flat white plane, or
2. lower down the DEM z-value

But I am not sure how to realize any of them exactly.
Does anyone have any idea how to get around this issue?

[image]

Same sort of idea also to lower down the existing DEM so that it won't emerge/ swell up beyond the Proposed DEM model.
Please see the example below:

The Yellow-green part is the existing DEM and I want to let it go right under the proposed (gray) DEM but not way to low like the flat plane.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are still looking for an answer: https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs/issues/167 helped me.

I created a -10 meter buffer of my DEM's extent and clipped the DEM in the QGi2Threejs Viewer (DEM properties->Clip with polygon layer) with this buffer.